# solidity how can payable?

Tags: solidity, payable

hihi this is my code

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract ValueIO {

 uint myidaaaa;

 uint price = 100000000 wei;

 function Input(uint feion) public payable {
     require(msg.value > price);  

     myidaaaa = feion;
 }

 function Output() public constant returns (uint,bool) {
     return (myidaaaa,true);
 }
}
```

i wish user input and change myidaaaa data and pay the 1eth to my contract

but i don't know how can do this

please help me my teach

thank you so much

(the photo is error note)

[image]

Comment: Can someone help? I want to know the specific code that can be payable. Thank you very much.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reverts because of your `require` statement. You are not sending any value to the method, therefore the `require` reverts.

Try adding value to the transaction - insert into the field `Value` at the upper right corner. For example 100000001. Then call your `Input` function with any input. `Output` will then give you the right data.

Comment: hi 
Lauri Peltonen 
thank you comment 
i Try the transfer function 
but also is err
maybe you would tell me where is my error
i am so sorry i am beginner
thank you so much!!

Comment: If you have further information about the problem, please edit your own question to include the information

Comment: I am so sorry 
I don't mean to offend
please forgive me